# Laravel 4 using regex to target month and date separately in created_at database fields

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, timestamp

I'm having a hard time coming up with an effective solution to a problem. I'm trying to display the day and month (example Jan 31) on a post while grabbing it automatically from my `created_at` timestamp in the database. I'm not very familiar with regular expressions in PHP.

I really feel like i'm making this overly complicated and there has to be a simpler solution.

Here is where i'm at

```
$month = $this->post->select('created_at')->where('id' ,'=', 1)->firstOrFail();

echo $month;
```

This outputs `{"created_at":"2014-01-31 22:35:59"}`

I want to target the `01` for the month and `31` for the day, each in separate variables.

Would regular expression be the best way to go about solving this? I tried exploding by `-`, but that just seemed messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, regular expressions would work but they're not quite the best tool for it. What you'll want to do is to treat it as a datetime and work from there, like so:

```
$created_at = $this->post->select('created_at')->where('id' ,'=', 1)->firstOrFail();
$month = date('m', strtotime($created_at));
$day = date('d', strtotime($created_at));
```

For full date formatting options, see the [date() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). If, for instance, you want "January", just use the 'F' option instead of 'm'.

However, for Laravel, you're a little bit in backwards order. The usual way to go about it is to first fetch the post using the Eloquent ORM, then just take the created_at field from there. Now, I don't know your model looks like, but something like this:

```
$post = Post::first(); // this will get the post with id of 1
$month = date('m', strtotime($post->created_at));
$day = date('d', strtotime($post->created_at));
```

In addition, Laravel automatically uses [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) for the created_at fields, so you could simplify it even more:

```
$post = Post::first();
$month = $post->created_at->month;
$day = $post->created_at->day;
```

If this is a task you do often, I'd build a custom function within your post model to take care of it:

```
// within post class
public function getMonth()
{
    return $this->created_at->month;
}

public function getDay()
{
    return $this->created_at->day;
}

// from somewhere else, e.g. a view
$post = Post::first();
echo $post->month();
echo $post->day();
```

Nb I haven't tested the code right now, but this should give you the right idea. :)

Comment: Wow that is quite the answer! Thanks a lot, i'm excited to try it out.

Comment: Np, hope you get it working. If I oopsed any syntax just let me know and I'll fix it.